# I deleted all instances of Netwonsoft.json and now my TFS 2017 build agent fails - how do I get it back?

Tags: json.net, tfsbuild

This has been plaguing us for some time and every time I update other NuGet package versions it seems to re-appear for some reason. If I use MSBuild to build my solution it works fine but using TFS build the build fails because it uses aspnet_compiler.exe and gives the following message:

```
error ASPCONFIG: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json,  
Version=11.0.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of 
its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the 
assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

The command I'm using that fails is:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler.exe -v 
localhost_53906 -p PICCS.WebServices\PICCS.WebHost\ -u -f PrecompiledWeb\localhost_53906\
```

This happens whether I use version 11.0.0.1 or 11.0.0.2 and I've narrowed it down to the website in the project - not a .csproj. I've tried deleting the Newtonsoft folders from my packages folder and re-getting them but that didn't help. Ultimately I deleted all newtonsoft instances from my computer and reinstalled versions 11.0.0.1 and 11.0.0.2 and then I can build using the command above. But now TFS build agent fails because it can't find Newtonsoft.json.9.0.1. How can I get that back? Reinstall VS? Reinstall .net? I tried just creating a new agent but that fails with this error:

```
Error: assembly specified in the dependencies manifest was not found -- package:
'newtonsoft.json', version: '9.0.1', path: 'lib/netstandard1.0/Newtonsoft.Json.dll'
```

Comment: What's the result if you build directly not through TFS in your build agent locally? The issue seems more related to your environment setting.  The build agent will not detect the environment changes after you installed it. It will only detect during the installation.

Comment: Did you remember the folders where you delete the files?

Comment: No - I just deleted it from everywhere. This is resolved for now. Next time I upgrade a NuGet package I'm sure it will reappear.